# Cannot import FTP_TLS on EC2

Tags: python, ftp, amazon-ec2, ftplib

I'm writing an FTP script in python on EC2 where I need to be able to import FTP_TLS for the connection.

`from ftplib import FTP_TLS`

Except, it gives me:

`ImportError: cannot import name FTP_TLS`

I can import FTP_TLS on my local python shell, but it fails on EC2.

What's going on?

EC2 Python 2.6.5 / Local Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTP_TLS is only supported in Python 2.7+.

You could upgrade Python on your server, or just grab `Lib/ftplib.py` from source:

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.1/Python-2.7.1.tgz
```

Put it in your load path and your `import` will work.

Comment: Just to include the source: http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html indicates that FTP_TLS was added in 2.7

Comment: I've installed python 2.7.5 but FTP_TLS still gives me the same error. Is it because 2.6 is still there?

Comment: Possibly. Try `python --version` in your console to check which one's running, and the shebang at top of your script to check whether it explicitly starts a specific Python.